# Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0. Both fix options crash my app

Tags: dart, sass, compass-sass

I need help with this deprecation issue, whichever one of them I choose they both crash my webapp. What should I do?

[image]

this is the calc option
[image: Changning to calc]

This is the math div option
[image]

Comment: It looks like your second error is regarding the address already in use. Are you sure that the port is not already used?

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing `@use "sass:math";` at the top?